# If $\operatorname{si}(x) =- \int \limits_{x}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\sin t}{t}\right)dt; x>0$ then:

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$\int \limits_{e}^{e^2} \left(\frac{1}{x}\left(\operatorname{si}\left(e^4x\right)-\operatorname{si}\left(e^3x\right)\right)\right)\,dx=\int \limits_{3}^{e^4} \left(\frac{1}{x}\left(\operatorname{si}\left(e^2x\right)-si\left(ex\right)\right)\right)dx$$

Actually in this question, I think the integral should be $e^3$ to $e^4$. But here it is given 3 to $e^4$. I wonder if this is a mistake or not. Can you tell me ?

Comment: You're right. It must be a typo.

Comment: it is noticeable that $ (e^2,e^4)$ and $(e,e^3)$ are interchanged throughout the equation. So if it is a typo, why would the author repeat the same line twice?